# Enqueuing multiple stylesheets with a child theme

Tags: child-theme, wp-enqueue-script, css

I've successfully enqueued a parent stylesheet and child stylesheet. I'd like to enqueue a third - ultimately a style.php file, but a second-style.css would be a good start.

It's not working for me though: can anyone tell me why?

```
function theme_enqueue_styles() {

        wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
        wp_enqueue_style('second-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/second-style.css');

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
```

I've tried registering the stylesheet first, and no cigar.

Comment: "_It's not working_" - what does it mean?

Comment: with your code I see the 3 stylesheets in HTML result. what is the problem ? edit your question to add more details.

Comment: No reason that shouldn’t work that I can see. What about it isn’t working. Is the link tag not being output in the head? Or are the styles just not applying?

Comment: Well, no rules on second-style.css is modifying the HTML, so I assume it's not recognising it.

Comment: Good point Jacob Peattie - the link is getting output into the header... Maybe it's just my CSS that's the problem!

Comment: Make sure your rules are [specific](https://www.w3schools.com/default.asp) enough to have an effect.